# validating form controls has more priority than navigating to some other url - angular2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular-validation

in an html page there is `<form>` with validation and `<a>` tag, like below.

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email"
        required
        email
        [(ngModel)]="model.email" name="email"
        #email="ngModel">
        <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched) " class="ha-control-alert">
          <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
          <div *ngIf=" !email.errors.required  && email.errors.email">Email is invalid</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
<div>
    <a [routerLink]="['/account/forgot']">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
```

the problem is that if input (email input) get touched by user but remains empty and after that user clicks on `<a>`, the page does not redirect and the error message for input will appear, after that if user clicks on `<a>` again the page will redirected, it seems checking validation and showing error message has more priority than navigating through `<a>` tag,this is strange, it seems it needs one more step interacting with user then navigation will work.  how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Try to add 'click' event and check if `<a>` really gets clicked.

Comment: @kemsky yes, it gets clicked, but exactly the same behavior, I put an `alert` inside click function and it will alert after checking `touced` and showing the error message

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your form is getting submitted when 'forgot password' is clicked. Try adding a login button inside `<form>`; then the routing should work fine.

Comment: I do not get you, and I do not think so! the `<a>` tag is not in `<form>` and you can see there is `(ngSubmit)="login()"`. If you mean something else please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using `css class` to show/hide element instead of using `*ngIf`